# Raw reading USB mass storage or SCSI

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, chkdsk, forensics, scsi

Wife's USB HDD has a slight issue where a folder refuses to open (NTFS filesystem). I have been able to image the drive with Linux but for one sector (sectors are 4096 bytes). Reading that sector fails:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=block skip=21647245 bs=4096 count=1
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 22.9317 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Replacing this sector with null bytes leads to the same symptom as in Windows, so the sector seems to be related to the problematic directory.

When accessing said sector dmesg output reads:

```
[20381.842495] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[20381.842506] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[20381.842510] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[20381.842514] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[20381.842517] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[20381.842531] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[20381.842535] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[20381.842539] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[20381.842542] Read(10): 28 00 01 4a 4f 8d 00 00 01 00
[20381.842557] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 173177960
[20381.842572] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 21647245
```

Is there a way to read this sector, raw, without CRC checking or whatever to actually try to recover some of the corrupted data?

I opened the enclosure: the HDD is native USB, no USB to SATA conversion.

**Edit:**
Tried ddrescue, but has not been able to recover the bad sector either. Reading 2Gigs around the bad sector the let the heads stabilize after the seek:

```
sudo ddrescue -s 2Gi -o 0 -i 87593373696 /dev/sdb blkk
GNU ddrescue 1.19
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:     2147 MB,  errsize:    4096 B,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:    88667 MB,   errors:       1,    average rate:    8488 kB/s
   opos:     1073 MB, run time:    4.21 m,  successful read:    1.06 m ago
Finished
```

Reading backwards (-R flag) failed too.

**Edit 2:** My planned second step was to use forensics to try to get the missing files. I first started looking at the MFT by hand, but this quickly gets very, very tedious. So I had the following tools on my list:

1. the Sleuthkit
2. ntfs-3g
3. scalpel
4. scrounge-ntfs

The Sleuthkit would not do anything useful, quitting very early complaining about errors in metadata structures.

With Ntfs-3g (now Tuxera) it is possible to mount the image with debug output:

```
sudo mount -o loop,ro,offset=258048,debug image2 ./mnt -t ntfs-3g
```

Trying to enter the faulty directory would trigger an error:

```
Index buffer (VCN 0x0) of directory inode 101874 has a size (24) differing from the directory specified size (4096).
```

Looking for that error in DuckduckGo lead me to the following post:
http://www.tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27054
**It turns out that the people at Tuxera / ntfs-3g actually encourage the use of Microsoft's CHKDSK to recover NTFS errors**

Running chkdsk on the disk was my third and last planned step, however it should be tried much earlier knowing that **it CAN be run on a disk image**, using for example OSFMount (http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html).

Most of the missing files and directories (if not all) have been recovered by chkdsk /f on the mounted disk image. More than a hundred errors (most of which being orphaned files) have been fixed.

**Edit 3:** I am accepting psusi's answer. Although not proved to be impossible, trying to read the bad sectors is certainly the most uncertain and difficult route for recovering data from a mildly damaged HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.  There is a SCSI command to do this, but you would still only be getting garbage, and it isn't supported on consumer level drives, especially not USB.  Whatever was in that sector is gone.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be garbage. It might be otherwise good data with one bad bit which fails the CRC. A looong time ago, I could use the linux generic scsi driver and an associated utility to issue commands directly to the device (I did scsi-level driver programming 18 years ago). If there are such raw commands, it might be useful to try.

Comment: This IS actually what I would like to do :) and decide by myself whether data read is total or only partial garbage ...

Comment: @Otheus, nope, doesn't work that way.  Before the CRC there is an ECC.  Up to a certain number of bad bits, it corrects, but as soon as you go over that, it starts spitting out garbage.

Comment: @psusi ECC on disk media? You got a reference for that?

Comment: @Otheus, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive

Comment: Seriously? An entire Wikipedia article? Not even a sub article or subsection?

Comment: @Otheus, do you really need that much handholding?  You couldn't be bothered to search the page for CRC?

Comment: If your knowledge of disk drives comes from Wikipedia, I have bad news for you. If you can't bother to link to a specific section, I'll have t assume you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Otheus, I pointed you there to show just how common knowledge this is and how easily you could have found it had you bothered.  It is clear now that you would prefer to engage in ad hominum attacks rather than actually learn something.

Comment: I'm sorry @psusi, please accept my more conciliatory tone. ECC in general does not work the way you suggest. I do know -- without wikipedia -- that HDDs use _multiple levels_ of  checks and error corrections. But: CRCs are performed on _blocks_ while ECC is at the bit- or byte-level.  If _you know_ ECC is also going on at a broader level, I'd like to see mfr specs promising that.  Otherwise, assume that n+1 errors will cause CRC to fail and if you are lucky, n is the minimum to foil ECC but fail CRC. Usually the minimum for n is 1 bit in 512 bytes of 10 bits, ie, 2 bad bits in 5120.

Comment: @Otheus, nope.. ECC is performed on blocks as well ( at least the reed-solomon type used in hard disks ).  They are designed to correct longer bursts of errors rather than the single odd error scattered here and there ( like a hamming code ).  The only way hard disk capacities have been able to scale the way they have in the last 15-20 years is by being able to correct numerous errors inherent in packing bits ever closer together, not just one bad bit in 512 bytes.